# How do I write a multiple dictionary to a csv file? [Python]

Tags: python-3.x

**I have a dictionary that looks like this**

```
     list2=[  {'char1': ['ABC',  'DEF',  'GHI',  'JKL',  'MNO','PQO','RST']},
              {'fact': ['1111', '2222', '3333', '4444']},         
              {'range1' : [ 'A123 ',  'B456',  ' C579']},

              {'char2': ['Hai',  'What',  'where',  'when ',  'who',  'has',  'had' ] },

              {'fact1' : ['11', '22', '33', '44']}]
```

**I have the following code:**

```
  import csv
  with open('my_file.csv', mode='w') as f:
      csv_writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
      csv_writer.writerow([list(i.keys()) for i in list1])
      csv_writer.writerow([list(i.values()) for i in list1])
```

**I want to put the results in a dataframe**

**Currently the results are stored in horizontally format I need to store  in vertical format.**

I'm trying to export it into CSV and have the tables look like this:

**Desired Output**

```
      char1    fact    range1  char2    fact
      ABC      1111    A123    Hai      11
      DEF      2222    B456    What     22
      GHI      3333    C579    where    33
      JKL      4444            when     44
      MNO                      who
      PQO                      has
      RST                      had
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```py
# data
list2 = [
 {'char1': ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL', 'MNO', 'PQO', 'RST']},
 {'fact': ['1111', '2222', '3333', '4444']},
 {'range1': ['A123 ', 'B456', ' C579']},
 {'char2': ['Hai', 'What', 'where', 'when ', 'who', 'has', 'had']},
 {'fact1': ['11', '22', '33', '44']}
]

# create a dataframe for each list
dfs = [pd.DataFrame(key_value) for key_value in list2]

# concatenate those dataframes along axis 1
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

Result of `df`

```py
  char1  fact range1  char2 fact1
0   ABC  1111  A123     Hai    11
1   DEF  2222   B456   What    22
2   GHI  3333   C579  where    33
3   JKL  4444    NaN  when     44
4   MNO   NaN    NaN    who   NaN
5   PQO   NaN    NaN    has   NaN
6   RST   NaN    NaN    had   NaN
```

Save to csv

```py
df.to_csv('filename.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Nice job @Chun

Thanks a ton!